# Expand the tensor by several dimensions

Tags: pytorch, tensor

In PyTorch, given a tensor (vector) of length `n`, how to expand it by several dimensions augmenting and copying each entry in the tensor to those dimensions? For example, given a tensor of size `(3)` expand it to the size=`(3,2,5,5)` such that the added dimensions have the corresponding values from the original tensor. In this case, let the size=`(3)` and the vector=`[1,2,3]` such that the first tensor of size `(2,5,5)` has values `1`, the second one has all values `2`, and the third one all values `3`.

In addition, how to expand the vector of size `(3,2)` to `(3,2,5,5)`?

One way to do it I can think is by means of creating a vector of the same size with ones-Like and then einsum but I think there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first unsqueeze the appropriate number of singleton dimensions, then expand to a view at the target shape with [`torch.Tensor.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html):

```
>>> x = torch.rand(3)
>>> target = [3,2,5,5]

>>> x[:, None, None, None].expand(target)
```

A nice workaround is to use [`torch.Tensor.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html) or [`torch.Tensor.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html) to do perform multiple unsqueezing:

```
>>> x.view(-1, 1, 1, 1).expand(target)
```

This allows for a more general approach to handle any arbitrary target shape:

```
>>> x.view(len(x), *(1,)*(len(target)-1)).expand(target)
```

For an even more general implementation, where `x` can be multi-dimensional:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(3, 2)

# just to make sure the target shape is valid w.r.t to x
>>> assert list(x.shape) == list(target[:x.ndim])

>>> x.view(*x.shape, *(1,)*(len(target)-x.ndim)).expand(target)
```

Comment: For a similar but different manipulation to affect a reshape of a 1D tensor ("orig_1d") into target rank of "src" tensor, where each element is mapped to the batch dimension (Slowest Changing Dimension = SCD), you could use: newShape= [-1,*(1,)*(src.dim()-1)]
    print("newShape = ", newShape)
    orig_1d_as_nd_at_fcd =  orig_1d.reshape(newShape), E.g.: 1d of size 5, becomes [5,1,1,1]  in case src is a 4D tensor